# Laravel pivot table- getting only first value in the foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to loop through additional column data in pivot table. However, I am only getting the first value in the first row and rest are showing empty. Here is in my Blade

```
@foreach($benefits as $benefit)
    @foreach($user->benefits as $benefitid)
        value="{{ $benefitid->id === $benefit->id ? $benefitid->pivot->employee_pay : '' }}"
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

For the checkbox, similar condition is working, but not for the data. Here is the working code for checkbox

```
@foreach($benefits as $benefit)
    @foreach($user->benefits as $benefitId)
        {{ $benefitId->id === $benefit->id ? 'checked' : '' }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I have a pivot table with following
*benefit_id*, *user_id* and *employee_pay*. The last one is the additional column. The relation is many to many.

I want to retrieve all the values in employee_pay column from the foreach loop. However, I am only getting the first value.

Comment: Please give a bit of information about your table structures, relation names, and exactly what you want to get.

Comment: Hi, information updated. Let me know if further info is needed.

Comment: You can watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6kX9U5xxqQ

Comment: This is good. Thanks. But 2 points: how to show existing values when editing and how to add data if there are multiple rows?